# Search & Replace text in RTF

Tags: rtf

I need to search & replace text in RTF.
Sometimes the RTF markup can make it hard, for example, in this situation:

```
415\f1\rtlch\lang1037  \f2\ltrch\lang1033 986-7020
```

When I want to find `415 986-7020` and replace it with `some text`.
I did not find any library which can parse/modify/rebuild RTF.

One thing to mention: I can't use windows environment for that.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Python/C#/Javscript, I actually don't mind :) I did try the RichTextBox Control of Windows.Forms but (for some reason) it will break/change my RTF, not keeping the original style.